# Is it a word or an abbreviation?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is a postcard from world war one, The card is part of a series of Military slang.
I understand Sperrfeuer as " Barrage ", can someone tell me what Jm means. I have tried dictionary's and on line without success.

Comment: _"can someone tell me what Jm means"_ No we can't without any more context here.

Comment: You should add a foto of your postcard.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with posting a picture, please at least try to cite the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

(Extended earlier comment)

I guess, it should read:

> Im Sperrfeuer

instead, which would make the asked *Jm* the standard preposition *im*, cf.  [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/im), meaning 2.

As you can see [here](http://resolver.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/SBB0000D64B00020001) (Book title *Im Völkerringen*, printed 1915), I and J are quite difficult to distinguish at that time. This already applies to print, but handwriting is even more difficult.

Comment: How does that explain what _Jm_ means?

Comment: @DavidVogt I understood that, but that doesn't explain what's written in that missing context though.